# How to apply the Empirical Rule to find the percentage?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means, confidence-interval

So I am working on this question but I don't know how to apply the Empirical Rule.

**Question:** A Cornell University researcher measured the mouth volumes of a large number of men and women and reported that the distribution of the mouth volumes for men is approximately bell-shaped with a mean of 66 cc and a standard deviation of 17 cc. Moreover, the distribution of the mouth volumes for women is also approximately bell-shaped with a mean of 54 cc and a standard deviation of 14.5 cc.

**a) Applying the Empirical Rule, what percentage of man has mouth volume
over 100 cc or less than 49 cc?**

Now this is what I did.

- **100-66=34 which is 2(17). Thus, 100 is 2 standard deviation to the right of the mean.**
- **66-49=17 which is 1(17). Thus, 17 is 1 standard deviation below the mean**

  From here, I don't know which formula to apply to get the percentage that I did for this question. So can someone help me solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empirical rule can be broken down into three parts: $(1):$ $68\%$ of data falls within the first standard deviation from the mean; $(2):$ $95\%$ fall within two standard deviations; $(3):$ $99.7\%$ fall within three standard deviations.

From $(1)$ and the fact that the Normal distribution is symmetric, it follows that $16\%$ will be above one standard deviation and $16\%$ bellow. From $(2)$ it follows that $2.5\%$ will be above two standard deviations and $2.5\%$ bellow.

Comment: Sorry but How did u know that the distribution is symmetric when you're only given the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Because a bell-shaped distribution is symmetric.

Comment: so I am assuming that every bell-shaped distribution is symmetric and the values will always be the same. (16% and 2%)

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful for you to look at this link: http://www.statisticshowto.com/empirical-rule-2/